# Use BoxCollider as area

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im trying to make a windzone only inside of box collider, managed to do it everything but it uses an a custom radius for now, I want to my radius be a box collider, is there any way to define my collider size as area?

Heres the code;

```
public class WindBehaviour : MonoBehaviour
{

  
    public float WindStrengthMin = 0;
    public float WindStrengthMax = 5;
    public float radius = 100;

    float windStrength;
    int i;
    RaycastHit hit;
    Collider[] hitColliders;
    Rigidbody rb;

    public BoxCollider m_Collider;
    float m_ScaleX, m_ScaleY, m_ScaleZ;

    private void Start()
    {
        m_ScaleX = 1.318647f;
        m_ScaleY = 10.24611f;
        m_ScaleZ = 25.30314f;
    }
    void Update()
    {
        m_Collider.size = new Vector3(m_ScaleX, m_ScaleY, m_ScaleZ);
        
        windStrength = Random.Range(WindStrengthMin, WindStrengthMax);
       
        hitColliders = Physics.OverlapSphere(transform.position, radius); ///instead of radius here should box collider radius

        for (i = 0; i < hitColliders.Length; i++)
        {
            if (rb = hitColliders[i].GetComponent<Rigidbody>())
                if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, rb.position - transform.position, out hit))
                    if (hit.transform.GetComponent<Rigidbody>())
                        rb.AddForce(transform.forward * windStrength, ForceMode.Acceleration);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well instead of using

```
hitColliders = Physics.OverlapSphere(transform.position, radius);
```

You can use [`Physics.OverlapBox`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.OverlapBox.html) like e.g.

```
var hitColliders = Physics.OverlapBox(m_Collider.center, Vector3.Scale(m_Collider.size, m_Collider.transform.lossyScale) * 0.5f, m_Collider.transform.rotation);
```

---

Btw instead of

```
if (rb = hitColliders[i].GetComponent<Rigidbody>())
```

personally I would rather use

```
if (hitColliders[i].TryGetComponent(out rb))
```

Comment: Hey, thanks!Seems like its working in the way I wanted, but for some reason force is given after I pass the collider, so its not inside of collider. Any idea why? I checked collider position its in right position but for some reason its not happening while object is in collider.

Comment: Are you sure the other conditions are true? E.g. are you sure while inside the collider the Raycast will hit something?

Comment: managed to fix it by changing a bit code of hitcolliders;

`var hitColliders = Physics.OverlapBox(transform.position,m_Collider.size);`

thanks man you saved me!